# Why does Rashi leave out an example?

Tags: rashi, parashat-lech-lecha, haazinu

In [Devarim 32:48](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.32.48?lang=bi&aliyot=0) the pasuk says:

> וַיְדַבֵּ֤ר יְהוָה֙ אֶל־מֹשֶׁ֔ה **בְּעֶ֛צֶם הַיּ֥וֹם הַזֶּ֖ה** לֵאמֹֽר
>
> That very day the LORD spoke to Moses

[Rashi on Devarim 32:48](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Deuteronomy.32.48?lang=bi) writes:

> **וידבר ה' אל משה בעצם היום הזה**
> ... **בִּשְׁלוֹשָׁה** מְקוֹמוֹת נֶאֱמַר בְּעֶצֶם הַיּוֹם הַזֶּה, נֶאֱמַר בְּנֹחַ "**בְּעֶצֶם הַיּוֹם הַזֶּה** בָּא נֹחַ וְגוֹ'" (בראשית ז')
> ...בְּמִצְרַיִם נֶאֱמַר "**בְּעֶצֶם הַיּוֹם הַזֶּה** הוֹצִיא ה'" (שמות י"ב)
>
> **And the Lord Spoke to Moses That Very Day**
> In **three** places in Scripture the expression בעצם היום הזה is used. It states in the narrative of Noah (Genesis 7:12<sup>1</sup>) **That very day** entered Noah … [into the ark]”...
> Of Egypt, too, it states, (Exodus All. 11) “**The very day** the Lord did bring [the children of Israel out of the land of Egypt]”...

However, there is another place in [Genesis 17:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.17.23?lang=bi&aliyot=0):

> וַיִּקַּח אַבְרָהָם אֶת־יִשְׁמָעֵאל בְּנוֹ וְאֵת כָּל־יְלִידֵי בֵיתוֹ וְאֵת כָּל־מִקְנַת כַּסְפּוֹ כָּל־זָכָר בְּאַנְשֵׁי בֵּית אַבְרָהָם וַיָּמָל אֶת־בְּשַׂר עָרְלָתָם **בְּעֶצֶם הַיּוֹם הַזֶּה** כַּאֲשֶׁר דִּבֶּר אִתּוֹ אֱלֹהִים
>
> Then Abraham took his son Ishmael, and all his homeborn slaves and all those he had bought, every male in Abraham’s household, and he circumcised the flesh of their foreskins on **that very day**, as God had spoken to him.

So we see that there are four places in which the term בְּעֶצֶם הַיּוֹם הַזֶּה is used<sup>2</sup>.

Why doesn't Rashi mention this place in his list?

1. Note: The words themselves appear on the next pasuk ([Genesis 7:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.7.13?lang=bi&aliyot=0)), It seems Rashi means the beginning of the storyline.
2. In fact, Rashi [there](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.17.23?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.17.23.1&lang2=bi) even gives the same basic explanation of why those words are used (To show that even if others wanted to stop him, they wouldn't have been able to).

Comment: See שפתי חכמים.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel In Lech Lecha or Haazinu?

Comment: On the haazinu 32:48

Comment: crosspost: https://judaism.codidact.com/q/278210

Comment: http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0323.htm#21

Answer (score 2):

This is not primarily a question on Rashi. As is the case for most of Rashi's comments, this passage is taken from an earlier midrashic source, in this case Sifrei # 337 (and parallels). Rashi did not leave out any examples; he merely reported the Midrash as he had it.

Some later commentators attempted to come up with some reason why the case of Abraham's circumcision does not fit into the same category as the others (e.g. Divrei Dovid and Sifsei Chachamim on the verse in Deuteronomy), but such answers tend to not account for the fact that Rashi and the Midrash say that there are three instances of this in the Torah, not that there are three instances of a particular type.

However, there is a slightly different version of the Midrash preserved in Yalkut Midrashei Teiman:

> בשלשה מקומות נאמר בעצם היום הזה נאמר בנוח בעצם היום הזה בא נוח במראות אורו שליום לפי שהיו אנשי דורו אומרים בכך וכך אם אנו מרגישים בו אין אנו מניחים אותו ליכנס בתיבה ולא עוד אלא אנו נופלים כשילים וקרדמות ומבקעים את התיבה אמר הב"ה הריני מכניסו בחצי היום וכל מי שיש בידו יבא למחות יבא וימחה באברהם נאמר בעצם היום הזה נמול אברהם שהיו אנשי דורו אמרו אלו ראינוהו לא הנחנוהו לימול אמר הב"ה הו נמול בחצי היום בגבורת היום ביום הכפורים עצמו ומי שיש בידו יכול יבא וימחה במצרים נאמר בעצם היום הזה הוציא ה' לפי שהיו מצרים אומרים בכך וכך אם אנו מרגישין בהם אין אנו מניחים אותן לצאת ולא עוד אלא אנו נוטלים סייפות וכלי זיין והורגים בהם אמר הב"ה הריני מוציאם בחצי היום לעיניהם וכל מי שיש בו כוח למחות יבא וימחה אף כאן במיתתו שלמשה נאמר בעצם היום הזה לפי שהיו ישראל אומרים בכך וכך אם אנו מרנישים אין מניחין אותו שהוציאנו ממצרים וקרע לנו את הים והוריד לנו את המן והגיז לנו את המליו והעלה לנו את הבאר ונתן לנו את התורה אין אנו מניחין אותו אמר הב"ה הריני מכניסו בחצי היום

In this version, Abraham's case is mentioned and it falls into precisely the same category wherein the term בעצם היום הזה is taken to be God's challenge to anyone to stop him. However, in this version the Midrash is saying that there are three cases in addition to the one being commented on, i.e. four in total, which is in fact true. It is saying that just like in the other three cases where this term is used it alludes to God's challenge to any naysayers, here too it alludes to God's challenge to naysayers.

Answer (score 0):

The locations that Rashi cites are actions by Hashem and not by human beings. Thus, the commentary by Rashi pointing out that Hashem performed the actives in broad daylight to show that he would prevent anyone from attempting to interfere. The fourth pasuk cited was about the action of Avraham which was done in brouad daylight in order to show that he did not care if anyone objeted. Additionally, Rashi in the locations cited points out that there were people who stated that they would prevent this from being done. In the case of Avraham, there were no people who stated in advance that they would prevent the circumcisions from taking place. Thus that pasuk was not relevant to the explanation.